# upload image script (.asp) works... but not on this server

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

Hihi,

I made a webpage for a restaurant two years ago in .asp 2.0 with
news feature and the well known _upload.asp script to upload image.

It has worked perfectly until some months ago - I was certain it was a
problem with the hosting company but they say all privilege are on.

(This is the error I get: SaveBinaryData error 800a0bbc)

Now I tried to copy/pase the same files from the same CMS system I made from
other webpages I did which are hosted at other companies - I pasted them
into the restaurant´s FTP area - and that throws that error (but other webpages with the same feature works perfectly)

Isn´t that a 100% proof that the issue is the hosting company?

Comment: Please post relevant code. Also, do you mean classic ASP or ASP.NET? Those are totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions issue.  Make sure that IUser and Network have full write access to the uploads directly.  Also can be limits they set on IIS for max http sizes.